# Como posso compactar diretório exceto pasta especifica?

Tags: ssh

Preciso com SSH compactar um diretório exceto uma pasta especifica dentro desse diretório.

- **pasta**: /public_html
- **exceto**: /public_html/wp-content/uploads/Vista/

Como posso realizar esta operação? Realizei um comando que estava na verdade excluindo os arquivos do ***exceto*** mas não é isso que eu quero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o argumento `--exclude` do comando `tar`:

```
tar -pczf public_html.tar.gz /public_html/ --exclude "/public_html/wp-content/uploads/Vista"
```

Comment: Isso não vai excluir os arquivos do **/Vista** né?

Comment: Não. Ele vai excluir os arquivos apenas do arquivo compactado.

Comment: Não posso excluir os arquivos.

Comment: @MarcosVinicius ele quis dizer que não vai adicionar ao compactado quando disse "Ele vai excluir os arquivos apenas do arquivo compactado"

Comment: Fique tranquilo. O argumento `--exclude` é referente ao comando `tar`, não tem nada a ver com o sistema de arquivos ou algo do tipo.

Comment: E quando eu usar zip ?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o parâmetro `--exclude` do [`tar`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tar) para comprimir tudo menos o diretório/arquivo especificado.

Exemplo com compressão bzip2:

```
tar jcvf arquivo.tar.bz2 --exclude="/public_html/wp-content/uploads/Vista/" /public_html
```

Comment: Isso não vai excluir os arquivos do **/Vista** né?

Comment: @MarcosVinicius Não. O parâmetro `exclude` serve para você especificar arquivos que serão **ignorados** pelo `tar`, ou seja, na hora da compactação, estes arquivos não serão incluídos.

Comment: E quando for ZIP ?